# TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I get the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\levanim\Desktop\Levani Predictive\cosinesimilarity1.py in <module>()
     39 
     40 for i in meowmix_nearest_neighbors.index:
---> 41     top_ten = pd.DataFrame(similarity_matrix.ix[i,]).sort([i], 
ascending=False[1:6]).index.values
     42     meowmix_nearest_neighbors.ix[i,:] = top_ten
     43 
TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable
```

for the following code. I'm new to Python and can't quite put my finger on how I have to change the syntax(if its a syntax python 3 problem). Anybody encounter this? I think it's to do with the ascending=False[1:6] portion and have spent some time banging my head against the wall. Hoping it's a simple fix but don't know enough

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine


enrollments = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\levanim\Desktop\Levani 
Predictive\smallsample.csv')

meowmix = enrollments.fillna(0)

meowmix.ix[0:5,0:5]

def getCosine(x,y) :
    cosine = np.sum(x*y) / (np.sqrt(np.sum(x*x)) * np.sqrt(np.sum(y*y)))
    return cosine

print("done creating cosine function")

similarity_matrix = pd.DataFrame(index=meowmix.columns, 
columns=meowmix.columns)
similarity_matrix = similarity_matrix.fillna(np.nan)

similarity_matrix.ix[0:5,0:5]
print("done creating a matrix placeholder")


for i in similarity_matrix.columns:
    for j in similarity_matrix.columns:
        similarity_matrix.ix[i,j] = getCosine(meowmix[i].values, 
meowmix[j].values)

print("done looping through each column and filling in placeholder with 
cosine similarities")


meowmix_nearest_neighbors = pd.DataFrame(index=meowmix.columns,
                                        columns=['top_'+str(i+1) for i in 
range(5)])

meowmix_nearest_neighbors = meowmix_nearest_neighbors.fillna(np.nan)

print("done creating a nearest neighbor placeholder for each item")


for i in meowmix_nearest_neighbors.index:
    top_ten = pd.DataFrame(similarity_matrix.ix[i,]).sort([i], 
ascending=False[1:6]).index.values
    meowmix_nearest_neighbors.ix[i,:] = top_ten

print("done creating the top 5 neighbors for each item")

meowmix_nearest_neighbors.head()
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the `False[1:6]` thing, anyway?

Comment: print out the top 5 closest items

Answer (score 5):

Instead of

```
    top_ten = pd.DataFrame(similarity_matrix.ix[i,]).sort([i], 
ascending=False[1:6]).index.values
```

use

```
    top_ten = pd.DataFrame(similarity_matrix.ix[i,]).sort([i], 
ascending=False), [1:6]).index.values
```

(i. e. insert `),` just after the `False`.)

`False` is the value of the `sort()` method parameter with meaning "not in ascending order", i. e. requiring the *descending* one. So you need to terminate the `sort()` method parameter list with `)` and then delimit the *1st parameter* of the `DataFrame` constructor from the *2nd one* with `,` .

`[1:6]` is the *second parameter* of the DataFrame constructor (the index to use for resulting frame)

Comment: tried this: top_ten = pd.DataFrame(similarity_matrix.ix[i,]).sort([i], ascending=False), [1:6]).index.values and got the SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Omit this second parameter, i. e. the part `, [1:6]`, check the result and let know if it is acceptable.

Comment: ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you can't do `False[1:6]` - `False` is a `bool`ean, meaning it can only be one of two things (`False` or `True`)

Just change it to `False` and your problem will be solved.

the `[1:6]` construct is for working with `list`s. So if you had, for example:

```
theList = [ "a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l" ] 

print theList      # (prints the whole list)
print theList[1]   # "b"    
print theList[1:6] # ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

In python, this is called "slicing", and can be quite useful.

You can also do things like:

```
print theList[6:] # everything in the list after "f" 
print theList[:6] # everything in the list before "f", but including f
```

I encourage you to play with this using [Jupyter Notebook](http://jupyter.org/) - and of course, read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)

Comment: hehe, after taking off [1:6], i know get the error: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

Comment: I believe you meant to use `#` instead of `//`?

Comment: Indeed! 3 years, and you're the first person to notice that. Thank you!