# Python combination with criteria and output in excel

Tags: excel, python-3.x, xlsxwriter

I have two lists and I want a combination which satisfies a particular condition for which I wrote the following program and printed the result in excel:

```
a = [1.01, 5.84, 13.86, 14.72, -12.45]

b = [6.42,5.67,12.51,0,7.23,8.45,9.11,18.24]

combination1 = [(x,y) for x in a 

                      for y in b]

c = [(1.01,18.24), (13.86,0), (5.84,0)]

combined_list = [combination1 and combination1 != c]

import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('jam.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

row = 0

for group in (combined_list):
    for col in range(2):
      worksheet.write (row, col, group[col])
    row += 1
workbook.close()
```

**Debug console shows**

```
worksheet.write (row, col, group[col])
TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable
```

Why is this not working?

**Intended Output**
The combination (x,y) x from a and y from b such that combination (x,y) in c is not included.

Comment: Please edit your question to fix the indent problems around your `for` loops.

Comment: @miken32 Done but the problem persists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44337101/typeerror-bool-object-is-not-subscriptable-python-3)

Comment: Typo: `(1.01,18.24,` and if you fix that, outputting `combined_list` gives you `[True]`

Comment: @PlikePotatao I have been trying to figure it out. Solutions?

Comment: @miken32 did you get the result in an excel sheet?

Comment: There is no result, that's my point. `combination1 and combination1 != c` is a boolean value, what are you expecting to be able to write to Excel?

Comment: @miken32 (x,y) x in a and y in b such that I do not get the combinations (x,y) mentioned in c

Comment: @miken32 if and else would be redundant here there is just one condition which I do not want.

Comment: What does `print(combined_list)` output. Now in your for loop `group` is an element of that and you're trying to subscript group. Is group also a collection or is it a Boolean?

Comment: @Dan The combination is generated as a tuple. All I am interested in is in a way to generate a combination which excludes specified combinations. So (x,y) in combination1 excludes the combinations mentioned in c.

Comment: Yes but did you actually look at what combined_list ends up being. I don't think it does what you think it does.